# Show the existence of an $\eta$

Tags: calculus

For $f: [0,\ln{2}] \Rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  ;  $ \eta \in [0,\ln{2}] $ and $f$ continuous show $\exists  \eta$ for which:

$$f(\eta) = \frac{1}{e^2-e}\int_0^{\ln{2}}{e^{e^x}e^xf(x)}dx$$

My intuition is to use the mean value theorem or intermediate value theorem, but I can't seem to get anything useful

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Use the substitution

$$u = e^{e^x}$$

then apply mean value theorem.